# Unhandled Exception: Location with the name "Asia/Yangon" doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone

I am trying to get the timezone depend on user os and now I got the error when I try to set location.Why my region timezone is not working.Here is my code

```html
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:task_management/models/task.dart';
import 'package:task_management/ui/theme.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:get/get.dart';

Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
  }
```

When I input Asia/Bangkok ,it's working

Comment: Does using `timezone/data/latest_all.dart` instead make a difference?

Comment: Or have you tried [updating the timezone database](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone#updating-time-zone-databases) by running the `refresh.sh` script?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to list all the timezone values, looks like Asia/Rangoon is present not Asia/Yangon .

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  var locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;
  print(locations.length); // => 429
  locations.keys.forEach((key) {
    print(key);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone(); return Asia/Yangon .How can I do that?